# Using IVsSelectionEvents.OnSelectionChanged for with the designer

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, vsx, vspackage

I'm trying to use IVsMonitorSelection to know when the user is selection a control (label, textbox, etc.) on the designer. So far I get events when the user click on item from the "Solution Explorer" window and when he click on the designer window, but when the focus is already on the designer window and he select another control, there's no event.

The last comment on a social.msdn [question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vswpfdesigner/thread/1160a310-806f-456a-a058-c3491acdeab4/) suggest it's not possible. But someone who asked [another question](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsx/thread/3c27061f-ea57-4cad-8795-3246a366301d) seem to be able to do it.

Is it possible or not to have a ToolWindow that know which control on the designer that is currently selected?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The property window knows which control is selected in the designer, so definitely you can get the selected control. Just do some more research

Regards
Muse VSExtensions